# How do I make a bash script continue part of a loop only if there is no error in the first step of the loop?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I currently have a .command file for Mac that contains the following:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv
do
     /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -async 1 "${f%.*}".mp4
     rmtrash "$f"
done
```

How can I tell bash to only execute rmtrash if ffmpeg doesn't produce an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for return value of ffmpeg command using `$?` or put `&&` between 2 commands like this:

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv
do
     /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -ab 128k\
     -ar 48000 -async 1 "${f%.*}".mp4 && rmtrash "$f"
done
```

As per the bash manual:

```
command1 && command2
   command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will this continue the loop if one file fails but there are more to convert?

Comment: Yes it will continue to loop.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the quick response. Off to converting!